# Excluding the first match, BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm searching for `a` tags within a table and I want to exclude the first `a` instance which is junk. Any solution please?

Syntax of the tags is the same so I can't use anything like `id=False` etc. I guess I'm restricted to introduce a range somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably just use `find_all()`, then slice the result:

```
all_a_tags = soup.find_all('a')
for tag in all_a_tags[1:]:
    process(tag)
```

I don't remember if `find_all()` returns a list or an iterator, so if you get an error message when you try to slice the `find_all()` result, wrap a `list()` around it:

```
all_a_tags = list(soup.find_all('a'))
for tag in all_a_tags[1:]:
    process(tag)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks rmunn. List() wraper was not needed btw.